# Application of the Binomial Theorem-remainder

Tags: modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

I am having a confusion in this question-

What is the remainder when $7^{103}$ is divided by 24?

I attempted it as follows - 
It can be written as

$(7^2)^{51} \cdot 7$

Which can be written as

$(24*2+1)^{51} \cdot 7$

Now using Binomial Theorem clearly the remainder should be $1^1 \cdot 7=7$

But the answer in most places is 18 and whereas in some sites it is 7!!

Which one is correct and why am I wrong if I am?

PS-for those who think i am correct please prove that they are wrong:)

http://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-algebra/binomial-theorem-for-a-positive-integral-index/application-of-binomial-expression.aspx

Check this one out also... you have to download the pdf and scroll down to almost the middle to find the question! https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=dVwUVeKtDoKyuATQ6IH4DA&url=http://www.arbindsingh.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Introduction-To-Binomial-Theorem.pdf&ved=0CC8QFjAG&usg=AFQjCNGErAyk6Qh_fO2nlD-XvlDyuMFblQ&sig2=HiEovIrDxhZy4DPIgGHA_w

Comment: I'm trying to create a site for "Indian Competitive Exams" and your question seems to be related to it, I think you would be interested to support it [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86609/indian-competitive-exams?referrer=uQtcXaMCGQOGlwjYmelKJA2) and spread the word to your friends?

Comment: Sure...Its a great idea

Comment: see http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23169/discussion-on-proposed-site-so-called-indian-competitive-exams

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. The remainder is $7$.

If you want another way to check, we can use modular arithmetic. This is where in arithmetic you replace a number by its remainder (with respect to $24$ in this case).

As you have shown, $7^2$ has remainder 1 modulo 24. This means $$7^{103} \equiv 7^{102} \cdot 7 \equiv 1^{51} \cdot 7 \equiv 7 \mod 24.$$

---

If you want, I can spell out the binomial expansion.

When you expand $(2\cdot 24 + 1)^{51}$, the result is: $$_{51}C_0 (2\cdot 24)^{51} +\ _{51}C_{1} (2 \cdot 24)^{50} + \cdots +\ _{51}C_{50} (2\cdot 24) +\ _{51}C_{51}$$

Since $24$ is attached to all but the last term, and $_{51}C_{51} = 1$, we have $$(2\cdot 24 + 1)^{51} = 24 \cdot M + 1$$

This means $$7 \cdot (2\cdot 24 + 1)^{51} = (7M)\cdot 24 + 7$$ and so the remainder after division by $24$ is $7$.

Comment: see this link  http://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-algebra/binomial-theorem-for-a-positive-integral-index/application-of-binomial-expression.aspx

Comment: It appears that they are actually computing the remainder after division by 50. Or something close to that.

Comment: so they are wrong right?

Comment: check this out also... you have to download the pdf and scroll down to get this question. https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=dVwUVeKtDoKyuATQ6IH4DA&url=http://www.arbindsingh.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Introduction-To-Binomial-Theorem.pdf&ved=0CC8QFjAG&usg=AFQjCNGErAyk6Qh_fO2nlD-XvlDyuMFblQ&sig2=HiEovIrDxhZy4DPIgGHA_w

Comment: They are indeed wrong.

Comment: its shocking that after solving such great problems they goof up on such easy ones

Comment: It happens all the time. You just forget something, or get distracted by something else,  while you are working. I wouldn't hold it against them.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. But both sources compute the remainder modulo $25,\,$ not $\,24,\,$ i.e.

$\,{\rm mod}\ 25\!:\ \color{#c00}{7^2\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\,7^{103}\equiv 7(\color{#c00}{7^2})^{51}\equiv 7(\color{#c00}{-1})^{51}\equiv -7\equiv  18\  $ by $ $ [Congruence Rules.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

Therefore the $24$ is a typo for $25$ in both sources.

Answer (score 0):

$7\cdot \left(48+1)^{51} = 7(48^{51} + \binom{51}{1}48^{50} +\cdots + \binom{51}{50}48 + 1\right) = 7 \pmod {24}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: see this link http://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-algebra/binomial-theorem-for-a-positive-integral-index/application-of-binomial-expression.aspx